# How to add north arrow to the project frame in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.12, north-arrow

I search for a way to add a north arrow to the project frame (and not in the composer frame- that i know how to do), in the blue mark place:

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add a **North Arrow Decoration** from the menubar:

```
View > Decorations > North Arrow
```

And set the relevant options as shown (the options shown are from QGIS 2.14 which allows customisation of the *Margin from edge* setting):

[image: North Arrow decoration]

Example:

[image: Example UK]

Comment: `View > Decorations > North Arrow` doesn't exist in QGIS 2.14 anymore.

Comment: @andrasz - In my QGIS 2.14.3-Essen, the option exists. Which QGIS 2.14.x version are you using?

Comment: I was completely wrong yesterday! I tried to find the north arrow in the print composer, without thinking of switching to QGIS. It's there.

Comment: @andrasz - No worries, glad you found it :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to add same graphics (drawing) to map canvas. But you can create grid via "vector->Research tools->Vector grid..." and add it as vector layer.

[image]